# What is the maximum output current of an OP27?

Tags: operational-amplifier

How much current can an OP27 supply (happily) ?

The closest thing I can find on the [datasheet](http://www.mit.edu/~6.301/OP27c.pdf) is the short-circuit current (~30mA).

Comment: It does say *"The output stage has good load driving capability. A guaranteed swing of ±10 V into 600 W and low output distortion make the OP27 an excellent choice for professional audio applications."*

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick 600 W? I bet you meant \$\Omega\$.

Comment: @jippie Yeah, I cut text containing an ohm symbol and somewhere between cutting and pasting it was unhelpfully changed to a W by Windows/Acrobat/Chrome/other. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is as close as you can get to an answer

[image]

It basically shows you the max current vs output load, all it takes is a division between the voltage and resistance.

As you can see it's about 40mA for 4v at 100 Ohm or 10v at 250 Ohm but as the load resistance increases the max current drops

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring performance issues like distortion and gain reduction, the maximum output current is limited by two things- the short-circuit protection circuitry and the maximum power dissipation. There does not look to be any direct guarantees on the former, and the latter has to be calculated.

[image]

Since there is not a guaranteed limit for the minimum short circuit protection current, you can either guess from the "typical" graph (20mA maybe is safe, well *maybe*), or the more conservative approach would be to look at the other specs and see if we can divine anything.

First thing to try is the output voltage swing spec, but it's specified into a 2K ohm load, so the guaranteed swing of +/-11.5 or +/-10.5 only represents less than 6mA.

\$A_{VO}\$ is guaranteed to be 600,000 or 800,000 (depending on the chip part number) when supplying +/-10V into a 600 ohm load. That current is +/-16.7mA. This is the number I would use, assuming power dissipation is not a problem. It's also echoed in the data sheet text, though that's not something you should generally rely upon.

So, tackling the power dissipation. The worst case there would be something like +/-15V supplies with the load at -10V and supplying 16.7mA into the load. That represents 417mW the chip has to dissipate. Quite a bit, an SOIC chip will be running at close to 90°C junction temperature, not good for a precision amplifier. If the load can be assumed to be grounded, things look better- a 16.7mA current into ground from +15 represents only 0.25W. Chances are your application won't even be that bad (into a dead short) so substitute numbers for the real situation.

In general if you need to use a precision amplifier such as the OP27, especially down to DC, it's better **not** to have unnecessary power dissipation on the chip. It will affect bias current, offset voltage, and can cause thermal "tails" on response. It's better to add a buffer after the precision amplifier.